# TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'browser_profile' in robot + selenium

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, gitlab-ci, robotframework

I have a pipeline that runs robot tests using the seleniarm/standalone-chromium as webdriver.
everething was fine until some days ago. It looks like the selenium updated to v4.10 and they removed the "browser_profile" parameter from the **init** method in the webdriver class as shown in this print:

[image]

found in this [link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e#diff-c87c150ed2a08f5293db58a06da8bf7f14c3a5582586c6270c1be661dfdd0985L204)

I started receiving the following error during the robot job of my pipeline:
[image]

the solution was obvious to me, downgrade the version to one below 4.10 and it would be fine, but...
it did not work.

I tried with many different versions but none of them worked.

my setup is:
one container for selenium that i run with the following command ->

```
docker run -d --rm -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size 2g --name webdriver seleniarm/standalone-chromium:4.9.1
```

and another custom container that have robotframework==6.0.2 and robotframework-seleniumlibrary==6.0.0

does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue (and a similar setup).

To solve it, I've updated the  dockerfile for my custom container.

Instead of only:

```
RUN pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary
```

Explicitly install selenium==4.9.1:

```
RUN pip install selenium==4.9.1
RUN pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary==6.0.0
```